# Sorting a random array using permutation

Tags: python, sorting, shuffle

I tried to sort an array by permuting it with itself
(the array contain all the numbers in range between `0` to its `length-1`)

so to test it I used `random.shuffle` but it had some unexpected results

```
a = np.array(range(10))
random.shuffle(a)
a = a[a]
a = a[a]
print(a)
# not a sorted array
# [9 5 2 3 1 7 6 8 0 4]

a = np.array([2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9])
a = a[a]
a = a[a]
print(a)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

so for some reason the permutation when using the second example of an unsorted array returns the sorted array as expected but the shuffled array doesn't work the same way.

Does anyone know why? Or if there is an easier way to sort using permutation or something similar it would be great.

Comment: The result of `a = a[a]` is very interesting, but it does *not* sort the array, unless some special coincidence happen. Your special case `[2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9]` provokes that coincidence. `random.shuffle` will only create that coincidence if you are very lucky.

Comment: Why did you expect it to get sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

There is no reason to expect `a = a[a]` to sort the array. In most cases it won't. In case of a coincidence it might.

### What is the operation `c = b[a]`? or *Applying a permutation*

When you use an array `a` obtained by shuffling `range(n)` as a mask for an array `b` of same size `n`, you are applying a **permutation**, in the mathematical sense, to the elements of `b`. For instance:

```py
a = [2,0,1]
b = np.array(['Alice','Bob','Charlie'])
print(b[a])
# ['Charlie' 'Alice' 'Bob']
```

In this example, array `a` represents the permutation `(2 0 1)`, which is a cycle of length 3. Since the length of the cycle is 3, if you apply it three times, you will end up where you started:

```py
a = [2,0,1]
b = np.array(['Alice','Bob','Charlie'])
c = b
for i in range(3):
  c = c[a]
  print(c)
# ['Charlie' 'Alice' 'Bob']
# ['Bob' 'Charlie' 'Alice']
# ['Alice' 'Bob' 'Charlie']
```

Note that I used strings for the elements of `b` ton avoid confusing them with indices. Of course, I could have used numbers from `range(n)`:

```py
a = [2,0,1]
b = np.array([0,1,2])
c = b
for i in range(3):
  c = c[a]
  print(c)
# [2 0 1]
# [1 2 0]
# [0 1 2]
```

You might see an interesting, but unsurprising fact: The first line is equal to `a`; in other words, the first result of applying `a` to `b` is equal to `a` itself. This is because `b` was initialised to `[0 1 2]`, which represent the **identity permutation** *id*; thus, the permutations that we find by repeatedly applying `a` to `b` are:

> *id* == *a*^0
>
> *a*
>
> *a*^2
>
> *a*^3 == *id*

### Can we always go back where we started? or *The rank of a permutation*

It is a well-known result of algebra that if you apply the same permutation again and again, you will eventually end up on the identity permutation. In algebraic notations: for every permutation *a*, there exists an integer *k* such that *a^k == id*.

**Can we guess the value of *k*?**

The minimum value of *k* is called the **rank** of a permutation.

If *a* is a cycle, then the minimum possible *k* is the length of the cycle. In our previous example, *a* was a cycle of length 3, so it took three applications of *a* before we found the identity permutation again.

**How about a cycle of length 2?** A cycle of length 2 is just "swapping two elements". For instance, swapping elements 0 and 1:

```py
a = [1,0,2]
b = np.array([0,1,2])
c = b
for i in range(2):
  c = c[a]
  print(c)
# [1 0 2]
# [0 1 2]
```

We swap 0 and 1, then we swap them back.

**How about two disjoint cycles?** Let's try a cycle of length 3 on the first three elements, simultaneously with swapping the last two elements:

```py
a = [2,0,1,3,4,5,7,6]
b = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
c = b
for i in range(6):
  c = c[a]
  print(c)
# [2 0 1 3 4 5 7 6]
# [1 2 0 3 4 5 6 7]
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 7 6]
# [2 0 1 3 4 5 6 7]
# [1 2 0 3 4 5 7 6]
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

As you can see by carefully examining the intermediary results, there is a period of length 3 on the first three elements, and a period of length 2 on the last two elements. The overall period is the **least common multiple** of the two periods, which is 6.

**What is *k* in general?** A well-known theorem of algebra states: *every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles*. The rank of a cycle is the length of the cycle. The rank of a product of disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of the ranks of cycles.

### A coincidence in your code: sorting `[2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9]`

Let us go back to your python code.

```py
a = np.array([2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9])
a = a[a]
a = a[a]
print(a)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

**How many times did you apply permutation `a`?** Note that because of the assignment `a =`, array `a` changed between the first and the second lines `a = a[a]`. Let us dissipate some confusion by using a different variable name for every different value. Your code is equivalent to:

```py
a = np.array([2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9])
a2 = a[a]
a4 = a2[a2]
print(a4)
```

Or equivalently:

```py
a = np.array([2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9])
a4 = (a[a])[a[a]]
```

This last line looks a little bit complicated. However, a cool result of algebra is that composition of permutations is **associative**. You already knew that addition and multiplication were associative: *x+(y+z) == (x+y)+z* and *x(yz) == (xy)z*. Well, it turns out that composition of permutations is associative as well! Using numpy's masks, this means that:

```py
a[b[c]] == (a[b])[c]
```

Thus your python code is equivalent to:

```py
a = np.array([2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9])
a4 = ((a[a])[a])[a]
print(a4)
```

Or without the unneeded parentheses:

```py
a = np.array([2,1,4,7,6,5,0,3,8,9])
a4 = a[a][a][a]
print(a4)
```

Since `a4` is the identity permutation, this tells us that the rank of *a* divides 4. Thus the rank of `a` is 1, 2 or 4. This tells us that *a* can be written as a product of swaps and length-4 cycles. The only permutation of rank 1 is the identity itself. Permutations of rank 2 are products of disjoint swaps, and we can see that this is not the case of `a`. Thus the rank of *a* must be exactly 4.

You can find the cycles by choosing an element, and following its *orbit*: what values is that element successively transformed into? Here we see that:

- 0 is transformed into 2; 2 is transformed into 4; 4 is transformed into 6; 6 is transformed into 0;
- 1 remains untouched;
- 3 becomes 7; 7 becomes 3;
- 5 is untouched; 8 and 9 are untouched.

**Conclusion:** Your numpy array represents the permutation *(0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 0)(3 <-> 7)*, and its rank is the least common multiple of 4 and 2, `lcm(4,2) == 4.`

Comment: first of all, thanks for the great answer, and it did addressed my first question (and much more), but is there a pythonic way to sort those kind of arrays? obviously arr.sort() will do the job, but maybe there is better way for my spacial case

Comment: @superbrain I assumed the first part demonstrated with enough clarity that there was no reason to expect a shuffled array to get sorted. The second part explains why the particular array accidentally got sorted.

Comment: Well, yes, if you can find the rank of `a`, then you can take the appropriate power of `a` using fast exponentiation. But 1) Finding the rank is not particularly easy and 2) This only works for permutations, *i.e.*, the `n` elements have to be 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1.

Comment: @eilontoledano Well, in this particular case, you could just write `a = np.array(range(10))`.

Answer (score 0):

it's took some time but I figure a way to do it.
numpy doesn't have this fiture but panda does have.
by using df.reindex I can sort a data frame by it indexes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
train_df = pd.DataFrame(range(10))
train_df = train_df.reindex(np.random.permutation(train_df.index))
print(train_df) # random dataframe contaning all values up to 9
train_df = train_df.reindex(range(10))
print(train_df) # sort data frame
```